# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, tensorflow

After running any command on my project directory i got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is I have installed this

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

and this

```
pip install psycopg2==2.7.4
```

on my virtualenv, but none of the commands fixed my issue.

I have checked all the postgres setting but I still have the same issue. Is that a problem with my postgres setting or installation issue??

Comment: Try to just import psycopg2 without naming it `Database`

Comment: You say you're using a virtualenv but your error trace shows you're not, since you're running python 2.7 from c:\python27. There's also a clear configuration issue here, since your import lib is fetched from python37 but you're running in python 2.7.

Comment: @dirkgroten if I run any command in virtualenv then error are  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Command' 
I have changed the configuration now another error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'player', Any idea what is happening with my project. I am new in Django

Answer (score 0):

Configure django database settings

Check settings.py and change Engine to django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2

Comment: thanks! @vivek i have already configured this database settings but still on same issue, maybe this is related to my Pythonpath

Comment: self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module. and 
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  Versions are different, can't run importing python 3.7 libraries in python 2.7

Comment: I did change the path now new error pops up Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001CA7974F288> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Ga\Apdt\Lcl\Programs\Py\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'player

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution
   upgrade pip
   Then do pip install psycopg2==2.7.4
2. Solution
   Install postgrsql (new version)
   Add /bin file of postgrsql folder path add to environment
   variable